# Encryption mode requires an initialization vector of size 16

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I'm trying to encrypt a string using mcrypt_encrypt but I'm getting this warning `Encryption mode requires an initialization vector of size 16`. This is the code:

```
<?php
$str = "hassan";
$key = "WKSaRVxscxa7eDrX0mLjU6OUphS6F1z0";

$block = 16;
$pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block);
$str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);


$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));

var_dump($encrypted);
```

And this is the output I'm getting

```
Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): Encryption mode requires an initialization vector of size 16 in C:\laragon\www\info\index.php on line 10
string(0) ""
```

Please, help me!!!

Comment: You haven't provided an IV at all, where are you stuck?

Comment: The IV must be specified as the 5th parameter in `mcrypt_encrypt()`. Note that [_mcrypt_](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php) is deprecated and insecure.

Comment: Yeah, this is old code. Has been working on a server. Migrated to new one and not working there. mcrypt extension is installed on new server. Okay, I'll check IV and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Last parameter is default parameter set to null. I don't think that would be a problem in my case.

Comment: Well putting an iv resolved the issue. But, how do I do it in the server? Why old code works like this.

Comment: Possibly the PHP versions differ. Up to PHP 5.5.x it was allowed to omit the IV for a mode with an IV (just a warning was displayed). In this case, an IV consisting of only 0x00 values was _implicitly_ used. As of PHP 5.6.x this is forbidden, i.e. for a mode with an IV an IV must be _explicitly_ specified, otherwise a `false` is returned. This considers that a static IV is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recreate the current operation then you should provide an IV consisting of 16 zero bytes (not just `null` or `'0'` characters). The all-zero IV was implicitly used before you had to provide the IV.

You are working with insecure code. The warning hasn't been added without reason, and `mcrypt` is an unmaintained library which desperately needs to be replaced. CBC is often not secure even if you provide a random IV.